# Check text format with preg_match

Tags: php, preg-match

I'm trying to check some texts with `preg_match`.

The text format is numbers separated with `,` no letters or anything else

just numbers + ","

For example : `10,50,30`

Lets say i want to ckeck this :

```
20,300,60  //ok
50  //ok..yes, ok even if there is no "," because there is no other number after it.
40,,60,60 // not ok..double ","
55,411, //not ok..contain "," at the end
70,800  //ok
```

I really tried many of things and wasted like 2 hours before i open this Q

Any idea please ?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the regular expression `/^\d+(,\d+)*$/`:

```
if (preg_match('/^\d+(,\d+)*$/', $string)) {
    // Matches
} else {
    // Does not match
}
```

If you want to match fractional numbers, use the following expression:

```
/^\d+(?:\.\d+)?(,\d+(?:\.\d+)?)*$/
```

Comment: Warning: preg_match() [function.preg-match]: No ending delimiter '^'

Comment: it works perfectly except if i'm trying to check numbers less than 1....For example:20,300,60,0.80  //should be ok, but it doesn't..any idea please? thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
preg_match('/^[0-9][0-9,]*$/', $string)
```

... will also accomplish what you're looking for, however, it will not be locale-independent, then again, most countries use the Arabic numerals we use in English, so I don't think this will be too much of a problem. All the best and hope it works out for you.

Comment: That regular expression says the string `,,,` is valid.

Comment: "55,411, //not ok..contain "," at the end". And what about additional `[+-]` for unary sign? :)